# jqでCloudTrailのJSON形式ログからCSV形式で抽出する方法

Tags: aws, json, jq

以下は、AWSのCloudTrailから取得したイベントログの抜粋です。

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventTime": "2018-01-01T01:11:11Z",
      "eventName": "StartInstances",
      "responseElements": {
        "requestId": "r-111",
        "instancesSet": {
          "items": [
            {
              "instanceId": "i-0XXX",
              "currentState": {
                "code": 0,
                "name": "pending"
              },
              "previousState": {
                "code": 80,
                "name": "stopped"
              }
            },
            {
              "instanceId": "i-0YYY",
              "currentState": {
                "code": 9,
                "name": "pending"
              },
              "previousState": {
                "code": 80,
                "name": "stopped"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

上記から、イベントが発生した日時とイベント名、インスタンスIDとcurrentStateのcodeをCSV形式で抽出する際、以下のような形式にしたいです。

```
eventTime, eventName, instanceId, code
2018-01-01T01:11:11Z, StartInstances, i-0XXX, 0
2018-01-01T01:11:11Z, StartInstances, i-0YYY, 9
```

ただし、responseElements.instancesSet.itemsの配下は1～N個の要素であり、インデックスを決めうちできないことがわかっています。

```
type event_history.json | jq-win64.exe -c -r ".Records[] | [.responseElements.instancesSet.items[] | (.instanceId,.currentState.code)] | @csv"
```

という方式だと、eventTime,eventNameが取得できないのと、
i-0XXX,0,i-0YYY,9
のようになってしまいます。
なにか方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

map を使ってみました。

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe
$ cat event_history.json |
  jq -r '
    .Records | map(
      [.eventTime, .eventName] +
      (.responseElements.instancesSet.items[]|[.instanceId, .currentState.code])
    ) | .[] | @csv'

"2018-01-01T01:11:11Z","StartInstances","i-0XXX",0
"2018-01-01T01:11:11Z","StartInstances","i-0YYY",9
```

Comment: こちらでも実際のデータを使用し、想定の形でデータが取得できることが確認できました。別の回答にもコメントしていますが、responseElements:nullとなるデータが含まれているため、.responseElements.instancesSet.items[]?とする必要がありましたので、引用される方は参考にしてください。

Answer (score 0):

例えば下記は如何でしょうか。

```
jq --raw-output ".Records[] | . as $r | $r.responseElements.instancesSet.items[] | . as $i | [$r.eventTime, $r.eventName] + [$i.instanceId, $i.currentState.code] | @csv"
```

テスト動作はこちらでご確認頂けます。 [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/KWnXPuLjTe)

#### 注意点:

- jqplayではシングルコーテーションを使用していますが、windowsのdocプロンプトで実行されているようですので、ダブルコーテーションを使用してください。

#### 参考:

- [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

Comment: 回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。  ただ、データを精査すると      "responseElements": null  となるものがあったため、実際の記述は以下になりました。    jq-win64.exe -c -r ".Records[] | . as $r | $r.responseElements.instancesSet.items[]? | . as $i | [$r.eventTime, $r.eventName] + [$i.instanceId, $i.currentState.code] | @csv"

Comment: @jervis1938 コメントありがとうございます。nullの要素を想定できずご迷惑をお掛け致しました。申し訳ありません。